# SELinux prevents my init.rc exec command to execute

Tags: shell, selinux, init.d, aosp

I've added a `exec` command at the end of `init.rc` file.

```
on property:dev.bootcomplete=1
    exec u:r:shell:s0 shell shell -- /system/bin/am start -n com.example.package/com.example.package.MainActivity
```

This `exec` runs in `u:r:shell:s0` SELinux context, from user `shell` and in group `shell`. But SELinux still believes in access denial:

```
[28.918751] init: Starting service 'exec 3 (/system/bin/am)'...
[28.920227] init: cannot execve('/system/bin/am'): Permission denied
[28.920356] type=1400 audit(22128374.236:11): avc: denied { entrypoint } for pid=3887 comm="init" path="/system/bin/am" dev="dm-0" ino=292 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
[28.921791] init: Service 'exec 3 (/system/bin/am)' (pid 3887) exited with status 127
```

That's wonderful when I issue the very same following command in `adb shell` and it runs successfully, having SELinux enabled.

```
/system/bin/am start -n com.example.package/com.example.package.MainActivity
```

This is `id` of `adb shell`:

```
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

So, why does my `exec` command fail even though it has exactly the same identity of `adb shell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem. There are two problems:

- You're not using the *"exactly the same identity of `adb shell`"*. There are a couple of groups to which `adb shell` belongs but they're not mentioned in that `exec` command.
- `/system/bin/am` on its own is not executable, it's a shell script and should be passed to `/system/bin/sh` to be executed.

So, here's the final and working `init.rc` statements:

```
on property:dev.bootcomplete=1
    exec u:r:shell:s0 shell shell input log adb sdcard_rw sdcard_r net_bt_admin net_bt inet net_bw_stats -- /system/bin/sh /system/bin/am start -n com.example.package/com.example.package.MainActivity
```

Comment: It's still valid for the latest Oreo (tested on Lineage 15.1). Great job!